# Analog output from USB6009 using python and NIDAQmx base on Mac OSX

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, nidaqmx

All, 
I'm attempting to use Python and DAQmx Base to record analog input and generate analog output from my USB 6009 device. I've been using a wrapper I found and have been able to get AI but am struggling with AO.
There is a base class NITask which handles task generation etc. The class i'm calling is below. The function throws an error when I try to configure the clock. When I do not there is no error but nor is there voltage generated on the output. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
class AOTask(NITask):
    def __init__(self, min=0.0, max=5.0,
                 channels=["Dev1/ao0"],
                 timeout=10.0):
        NITask.__init__(self)

        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.channels = channels
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.clockSource ="OnboardClock"
        sampleRate=100
        self.sampleRate = 100
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.samplesPerChan = 1000
        self.numChan = chanNumber(channels)

        if self.numChan is None:
            raise ValueError("Channel specification is invalid")

        chan = ", ".join(self.channels)


        self.CHK(self.nidaq.DAQmxBaseCreateTask("",ctypes.byref(self.taskHandle)))
        self.CHK(self.nidaq.DAQmxBaseCreateAOVoltageChan(self.taskHandle, "Dev1/ao0", "", float64(self.min), float64(self.max), DAQmx_Val_Volts, None))
        self.CHK(self.nidaq.DAQmxBaseCfgSampClkTiming(self.taskHandle, "", float64(self.sampleRate), DAQmx_Val_Rising, DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps, uInt64(self.samplesPerChan)))

    """Data needs to be of type ndarray"""
    def write(self, data):
        nWritten = int32()
      #  data = numpy.float64(3.25)
        data = data.astype(numpy.float64)
        self.CHK(self.nidaq.DAQmxBaseWriteAnalogF64(self.taskHandle,
            int32(1000), 0,float64(-1),DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel,
            data.ctypes.data,None,None))
      #  if nWritten.value != self.numChan:
      #  print "Expected to write %d samples!" % self.numChan
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the wrapper you found? That would be helpful for others working with similar environments.

Answer (score 1):

Your question covers two problems:

1. Why does `DAQmxBaseCfgSampClkTiming` return an error?
2. Without using that function, why isn't any output generated?

## 1. Hardware vs Software Timing

> *rjb3 wrote:*
>
> > The function throws an error when I try to configure the clock. When I do not there is no error but nor is there voltage generated on the output.

Your program receives the error because the USB 600x devices do not support hardware-timed analog output [1]:

> > *The NI USB-6008/6009 has two independent analog output channels that can generate outputs from 0 to 5 V. All updates of analog output channels are software-timed. GND is the ground-reference signal for the analog output channels.*

"Software-timed" means a sample is written on demand by the program whenever `DAQmxBaseWriteAnalogF64` is called. If an array of samples is written, then that array is written one at a time. You can learn more about how NI defines timing from the DAQmx help [2]. While that document is for DAQmx, the same concepts apply to DAQmx **Base** since the behavior is defined by the devices and not their drivers. The differences are in how much of the hardware's capabilities are implemented by the driver -- DAQmx implements everything, while DAQmx Base is a small select subset.

## 2. No Output When Software Timed

> *rjb3 wrote:*
>
> > When I do not there is no error but nor is there voltage generated on the output.

I am not familiar with the Python bindings for the DAQmx Base API, but I can recommend two things:

1. Try using the installed **`genVoltage.c`** C example and confirm that you can see voltage on the ao channel.

   - Examples are installed here: `/Applications/National Instruments/NI-DAQmx Base/examples`
   - If you see output, you've confirmed that the device and driver are working correctly, and that the bug is likely in the python file.
   - If you don't see output, then the device or driver has a problem, and the best place to get help troubleshooting is the NI discussion forums at http://forums.ni.com.
2. Try porting **`genVoltage.c`** using the python bindings. At first glance, I would try:

   - Use `DAQmxBaseStartTask` before `DAQmxBaseWriteAnalogF64`
   - **Or** set the `autostart` parameter in your call to `DAQmxBaseWriteAnalogF64` to true.

## References

[1] **NI USB-6008/6009 User Guide And Specifications :: Analog Output** (page 16)

http://digital.ni.com/manuals.nsf/websearch/CE26701AA052E1F0862579AD0053BE19

[2] **Timing, Hardware Versus Software**

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370466V-01/TOC11.htm